# Help translating Rails Sqlite query to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I use the following code to help find sales for the current month.  My development db is SQLite, but I'm using Heroku for production, which uses PostgreSQL.  So I am getting an strftime function doesn't exist error.  How would I translate this, and is there a way to translate it so that it still works when querying my dev SQLite db as well?

```
sales = current_user.location.sales.find( :all,
                                          :conditions => ["strftime('%Y', date) = '?'
                                                          AND strftime('%m', date) = ?",
                                                          Date.today.year,
                                                          Date.today.strftime('%m')],
                                                          :order => "date")
```

Comment: Using sqlite for development and postgres for deployment is asking for trouble. Why not develop on postgres?

Comment: @Denis I am currently working on installing postgres to develop on.  I just started on sqlite because I'm pretty new and didn't know that Heroku was using postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres does not support strftime. You can find a list of supported date/time functions [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html).

```
sales = current_user.location.sales.find( :all,
                                          :conditions => ["extract(year from date) = '?'
                                                          AND extract(month from date) = ?",
                                                          Date.today.year,
                                                          Date.today.strftime('%m')],
                                                          :order => "date")
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was a little unclear about how to use those functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think to_timestamp or to_char are the analogous Postgres functions you want to take a look at. The docs are pretty straightforward; basically similar to strftime with different template patterns: [Postgres Datatype Formatting Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/functions-formatting.html)

Maybe more than you're interested in, but I would really recommend running Postgres locally if you're doing a lot of work with Heroku.  It will save you quite a bit of pain down the road.

Comment: Yes.  I plan to start running Postgres locally, although getting that up and running is causing trouble for me too :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the sales figures for the current month, this might be a more appropriate, database agnostic query.

current_user.location.sales.where(:date => (Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now)).order("date")

Comment: Thanks.  This works well too, but caused a different issue for me when I try to calculate the sum of each sales column and the sales variable is empty.  I ended up going with the postgres functions and switching my dev db to postgres.